# How should I store profile photos database/server-side for an Android app?

Tags: android, database, web-services, postgresql

I want users of my app to be able to view a gallery of profile photos on their phone but I'm not sure about the best way to store the gallery on the server? I'm using Postgres and a Java web service.

Should I store the images (or only a thumbnail) on the database or store only the paths and use a separate web server as I have read some people do? I wanted to make it as Android-based as possible so I wouldn't have to rely on having a web server to serve photos, but is there no way around it?

I have read about Postgres extensions to hold image files but I don't know if this is the most efficient way or not (I suspect it wouldn't be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really comes down to the size of the photos and how many of them you plan to be storing. Sometimes the database can be a viable option to store small thumbnail images, but generally this probably isn't the cheapest or most scalable solution but could avoid system complexity for a small project. For most projects I would go for file system/blob storage for images.

Comment: @Dusan thanks guys. I never thought of storing them in the file-system, I thought the only way I could retrieve them would be either through a db/web server, but it makes sense I guess. If either of you have a link to a small explanation of how to do this, that would be cool, but it seems simple enough I think.

Answer (score 1):

You should store both your full-size photos and thumbnails in the file system and store only paths in database. This would be more performance efficient.

You will probably need web server in order to protect who can see which photo.